# Bounding distance between solutions to differential equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider $x$, $y$ solutions to the problems $x' = f(t,x(t))$ and $y' = g(t,y(t))$ in an interval $[t_0, t_1]$ contained in an open set $D$. I want to show that if $f$ is Lipschitz continous with constant $L$ and $M = \max \{ |f(t,z)-g(t,z)| : (t,z) \in D\}$ then:
$$ |x(t)-y(t)| \leq (|x(t_0)-y(t_0)| + M(t_1-t_0))e^{L(t_1-t_0)} $$

Since $x,y$ satisfy $$x(t) = x_0 + \int^{t}_{t_0} f(s, x(s)) ds$$
$$y(t) = y_0 + \int^{t}_{t_0} g(s,y(s))$$
we can bound the difference as:
$$ |x(t) - y(t)| \leq |x(t_0) - y(t_0)| + \int^t_{t_0} |f(s,x(s)) - f(s,y(s))| ds + \int^t_{t_0} |f(s,y(s)) - g(s,y(s))| ds$$
and substituting:
$$|x(t) - y(t)| \leq |x(t_0) - y(t_0)| + L \int^t_{t_0} |x(s) - y(s)| ds + M(t_1 - t_0)$$

But I'm just having a lot of trouble further bounding this expression. Can you give me any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is direct once you use the Gronwall Lemma. Notice:
$$ |x(t) - y(t)| = A + B \int^t_{t_0} |x(s)- y(s)| ds $$ where $A = |x(t_0) - y(t_0)| + M(t_1-t_0)$ and B=$L$. By the Gronwall Lemma, this implies:
$$ |x(t) - y(t)| \leq Ae^{B(t-t_0)}$$
which is the result we were searching for.